# Как реализовать плавное движение камеры?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда я меняю направление движения по X, камера меняет тоже направление (на видео более понятно) => https://skr.sh/v4yFemW4s8k?a

У меня есть небольшой код делает само движение камеры плавным, но не решает этой проблемы (прикладываю видео как он работает) => https://skr.sh/v4yNMKxPC4H?a

Нужно чтобы когда игрок поворачивался в другую сторону, камера не поворачивалась вместе с ним, но продолжала следовать за ним

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {

    [HideInInspector]
    public Vector3 targetPos;

    private float smoothMove = 1f;

    void Start() {
        targetPos = transform.position;
    }

    void Update() {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPos, smoothMove * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
```

Comment: перефразируй что ты хочешь получить и в чем проблема

Answer (score 1):

В недавнем проекте для следующей за персонажем камеры я использовал вот этот код, может он и тебе поможет:

```
public class FollowCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform _cameraTarget = null;
    [SerializeField] private float _smoothTime = 0.2f;
    [SerializeField] private float _moveOrientationScale = 0f;

    private Vector3 _velocity = Vector3.zero;

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        var targetPosition = new Vector3(_cameraTarget.position.x, _cameraTarget.position.y, transform.position.z);

        AddMoveOrientation(ref targetPosition);

        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPosition, ref _velocity, _smoothTime);
    }

    private void AddMoveOrientation(ref Vector3 targetPosition)
    {
        if (_velocity.x > 0)
        {
            targetPosition += Vector3.right * _moveOrientationScale;
        }
        else
        {
            targetPosition -= Vector3.right * _moveOrientationScale;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, код идеально подошел